# Can Firebreath be used on armx86 platform

Tags: firebreath

Firebreath can be used in Windows and Linux like Ubuntu etc., but can it be used in armx86 platform. Can we cross compile using arm x86 cross chain toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, nobody has tried. You'd have to try it and find out.

There is no technical reason that I know of that it couldn't be; look into cross-compiling with cmake.